# Concrete Apartment Balcony Repair

Tags: concrete, outdoor

[image: damage with hand as reference][image: close up of damage]

There seems to be two layers on top of the concrete:

- the thicker, white-ish layer next to concrete
- the gray, textured layer on top

I'd like to fix this up, but have no idea where to start. Would really appreciate help to

- Identify the layers
- Determine steps required to fix

Comment: What the heck are you using for chain lube ?

Comment: That is a skim coat, or a sprayed texture. you may match the texture but the color will be off. Match the texture and then paint is your best option to hide the flaking coating. I would think your cleaning did more damage than the chain oil.

Comment: Thanks @EdBeal! I should have taken some before pictures. At the time I was confident that the oil did enough damage that it was too far gone, but I'm definitely no expert! To confirm my approach: 1. Patch the area with this [skim coat & patch](https://www.homedepot.ca/product/custom-building-products-skim-coat-patch-cement-underlayment11-34kg/1000668621#). 2. Find similar paint (mix with texture aggregate?). 3. apply paint, wait to dry. Does that sound right to you?

Comment: Yes this is the method I have used to repair failing coatings in the past.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, if it didn't look so new I might think it was a type of flooring that was common in the mid-20th century known as *magnesite*, also called "Diato" I believe. That was a mineral pour-in-place material that was often used to protect concrete decks and other outdoor (and indoor) floors and structures, like stairs.

I don't see any chance for you to try to fix this with it being un-noticeable. The closest you might get is to use a hard-setting repair plaster to fill just below the level of existing, then buy some paint to match, add aggregate to try to match the anti-slip treatment on there, and brush/roll to blend. I still think it will show, and it might crack around the repair because different materials tend to do that due to different flex, expansion and contraction properties.

Good luck.